# Spring: NoClassDefFoundError org/springframework/util/StreamUtils

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Народ, всех приветвую. Столкнулся с проблемой при получении ответа от сервера через ajax. Неполучаю Строку которую передаю с помощью @ResponseBody

```
public class MsgController {

@Autowired
private MsgService msgService;


@RequestMapping("/ajax")
public ModelAndView helloAjaxTest() {
    return new ModelAndView("ajax", "message", "Spring MVC Example with AJAX call");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxtest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String ajaxResponse(){
    String text = "It should be response from DB";
    return text;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/saw", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String saw(Model model){
   // model.addAttribute("message",new Message());
    model.addAttribute("msg", msgService.getMessage(1));
    return "saw";
}
```

а вот и сам скрипт в  ajax.jsp:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <TITLE>Spring MVC Example with AJAX call</TITLE>


  <script type="text/javascript"
          src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function actAjax() {
      $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url : "ajaxtest.html",
        success : function(data) {
          $('#result').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var intervalId = 0;
    intervalId = setInterval(actAjax, 6000);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
  <br> <br> ${message} <br> <br>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <br>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Желанной строки: "It should be response from DB" к сожалению не неблюдаю.Выходит только текст от ModelAndView а через интервал: status 500.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос лог сервера и сообщения из отладчика браузера

Comment: А ещё добавьте логгирование при вызове методов

Comment: 27-Feb-2019 13:06:39.484 SEVERE [http-nio-8085-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [myBatisServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/StreamUtils] with root cause
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/StreamUtils

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError org/springframework/util/StreamUtils не хватает в classpath

Comment: GET http://localhost:8085/ajaxtest.html 500
send @ jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6
ajax @ jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6
actAjax @ ajax.html:11
setInterval (async)  
(anonymous) @ ajax.html:23

Answer (score 1):

Судя по сообщению об ошибке:

> 27-Feb-2019 13:06:39.484 SEVERE [http-nio-8085-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [myBatisServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/StreamUtils] with root cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/StreamUtils

У Вас происходит ошибка во время выполнения запроса, class loader не может найти класс `org/springframework/util/StreamUtils`

`StreamUtils` был добавлен `Spring 3.2.2.`  По всей вероятности Вам необходимо обновить версию `Spring`

Comment: При изменении Спринга на версию 3.2.2 выдает другие ошибки. Но подгрузив этот запрос к проекту с более свежей версией, всё заработало и долгожданную строку я наконец таки и увидел. Спасибо.